# How to get reponse data after post form data to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, form-submit

I have this html:

```
<form class="form-control" target="upload-profile-picture" action="<external link>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" data-bind="event: { change: function(vm, ev) { uploadImage(ev, $element.files[0]);} }" />
    <iframe id="upload-profile-picture" name="upload-profile-picture" class="hidden"></iframe>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="hidden"></button>
</form>
```

and script:

```
function uploadImage(ev) {
    $(ev.target).siblings('button:first').click();

    $(ev.target).siblings('iframe#upload-profile-picture').load(function() {
        console.log($(this).contents());
    });
}
```

I get the error:

```
SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:65147" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

form action is post image to API which is hosted at another domain, I want to get the reponse information but getting this error. It's cannot post file via ajax because an API does not support.

How to get the reponse data?

**Update**:

When I use ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<external link>",
    data: {file: file},
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
});
```

This is the response:

```
errorCode: 500
message: "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"
reason: "API error"
stackTrace: null
```

Comment: What exactly does that API not support about AJAX? Is there an error message?

Comment: Where is the iframe getting its src?

Comment: This is a really bad way to access APIs, so you must explore whether you can use AJAX.

Comment: I dont have permission with API, I just have permission to call it.

Comment: Try using the jQuery AJAX call at http://digipiph.com/blog/submitting-multipartform-data-using-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: @Zak: still get the same errorCode 500

Comment: Is it possible you could post, give a link to or create a JS Fiddle with your full code?

Comment: Tried with only ajax ? , without `form` element ? What format does api expect `file` , or `img` to be ?